# Keycloak 18.0.2 javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 400 Bad Request

Tags: keycloak

I noticed tons of errors in the Keycloak 18.0.2 logs:

```
WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-9796) type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=SomeName, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=*******, error=cookie_not_found, identity_provider=facebook

ERROR [org.keycloak.services.resources.IdentityBrokerService] (executor-thread-9796) unexpectedErrorHandlingRequestMessage: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.IdentityBrokerService.parseSessionCode(IdentityBrokerService.java:1060)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.IdentityBrokerService.performLogin(IdentityBrokerService.java:373)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor407.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:192)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:141)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:32)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:151)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:42)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1212)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:163)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:67)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:55)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1212)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:163)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$5.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:380)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$5.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:358)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1212)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:163)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.integration.web.QuarkusRequestFilter.lambda$createBlockingHandler$1(QuarkusRequestFilter.java:71)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$null$0(ContextImpl.java:159)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:100)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:157)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$13.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:543)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

But everything is working fine.. what could be causing this?